# How to reduce or remove triangles overlapping in Away3D

Tags: actionscript-3, away3d

I am looking for useful tips for reducing or removing triangle overlapping in Away3D.
I already tried to increas segmentsW and segmentsH but it doesn't solve the problem.
Here is a snapshot of my problem (The complex cubes are made of Plane objects, Maybe there is a better way to build the complex cubes ?) :
[image]
[image]
Alternatively does other flash 3d engines produces betters results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import away3d.core.render.Renderer; 
view = new View3D({renderer:Renderer.CORRECT_Z_ORDER}); 
You also can try "pushfront" or "pushback" properties, set to true to the planes meshes if these are planes... 
there are other ways, but looking at your example, one of these should be enough 
and you should be able to set the face count back to minimum

Answered by [Fabrice Closier](http://blog.closier.nl/) on [Away3D.dev](http://groups.google.com/group/away3d-dev/browse_thread/thread/1a55369922e65995) (he don't need points ; ))